# Логирование базы данных Oracle10

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Есть служба написанный на C++,событийность вызывает определеные функции для записи данныхв базу данных, где исходников почти нет,рывками.
Вот у меня пропадают данные, в определенных таблицах,из-за этого последующие таблици теряют данные.

Хотел посмотреть логи, но как то все не сошлось.
первое смотреть select * from v$sql,в полях есть clob, его открыл, но не вижу всех логических запросов.
У меня появляется запись в field, но я не вижу запроса на insert into,update.

Так же в корне базы данных нашел логи redo01-03 (открыть не знаю как и для чего они тоже не понял)
нашел alert_namedaytabase но он пишет в redo01  которые я открыть не знаю как.

Подскажите где я могу найти exeption неудачные попытки записи или полный список запросов, что значит REDO01 и как открыть его?

Comment: А зачем открывать REDO логи, что вы там хотите увидеть?

Comment: ищу все что модет помочь, а что там вообще?
Ищу запросы которые не записались в базу данных

Comment: Это служебные файлы. БД не ведёт по умолчанию логирование запросов.

Comment: Как поставить, логирование?

Comment: В двух словах на этот вопрос не ответить. Самое простое, это вести логи на стороне клиента, т.е. ваша служба должна протоколировать что она делает. В первую очередь ищите в ней возможность включить логгирование.

Comment: Исключенно, я думал дописать код на с++ хотя бы в тхт файл, но он обгрызанный, не соберётся. Хотя. В v$sql есть запросы которые были.

Comment: Если нет возможности изменить  вашу службу написанную на C++, то вы должны её выключить как можно скорее, если вам дороги данные в БД. Если трассировка в БД была выключена, то теперь шанс востановить, что ваша служба изменила (или наоборот - не изменила когда надо было), почти равен 0. Теоритически возможно, но временные затраты будут несравнимы с пользой от достигнутого результата.

Comment: Включите аудит на нужные вам таблицы и посмотрите журнал аудита. «Вот у меня пропадают данные, в определенных таблицах» Вот эта фраза непонятна: у Вас эта служба тайком удаляет данные из базы, или она просто молча не пишет нужные? (и вы хотите найти эти неуспешные попытки вставки?)\

Comment: REDO-логи руками не трогайте. Это N ротирующихся по кругу файлов, куда параллельно с записью в базу пишутся все успешные незакомиченные изменения. Они нужны для рестарта экземпляра после сбоя, а также для сервера наката (если он есть).